# c function calling error in printf()

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int adder(int,int);
void main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("enter nos");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    adder( a,b);
    printf("sum is %d",adder);
    getch();
}
int adder(int x,int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

this program is not working.I think the code is right.Can you point out the error?

Comment: If your code does not work, suppose it is correct is not an efficient starting point to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`adder` is a function, what you should `printf` is its return value.

And as @JonathanLeffler said, it's better to add a newline at the end if you want to ensure the output appears timely. So,

change

```
adder( a,b);
printf("sum is %d",adder);
```

to:

```
int result = adder(a,b);
printf("sum is %d\n", result);
```

or to:

```
printf("sum is %d\n", adder(a, b));
```

Comment: Yes. I've added it in my post.

Comment: And add a newline at the end to ensure the output appears timely.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not sure about it, you mean add "\n" to cause a flush? Or just make the output format easier to see the result?

Comment: If you're using a Unix-like system, it is best to use a newline at the _end_ of each output when you want it to appear.  If you wait for input (with `<conio.h>` and `getch()` on Windows), then it presumably works OK because everybody does it, but it might not work as well elsewhere (ignoring the issue that neither `<conio.h>` nor `getch()` is readily available on Unix — there are ways to use a `getch()` from the Curses library, but you have to do setup and cleanup work to use that).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the explanation, I've added it to my post. So happy I could learn sth new, even if the one made the answer is me.